# Socket does not receive any data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, network-programming

I have a C# Server and this Java client in Android Studio:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.107", 7778);
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (true) {
                currentMessage = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println(currentMessage);

                Thread.sleep(200);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error: " + e.toString() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

I have tested the Server with Telnet and the messages a going out as they should, so im almost certain, that the problem somewhere in the client code.
I have also tried using a DataInputStream instead of a BufferedReader, but it gives me the same results. Also I don't get any Exeptions.

I have these Permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Your android code is not receiving any messages??

Comment: "it it gives me the same results" - What are the results?

Comment: Is the server adding a new line (`\n`) at the end of the message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readLine()` blocks until there is a full line (terminated by either `\r\n` or `\n`) received in the underlying buffer (or the end of the steam has been reached). So unless your server is terminating the data with a linebreak, your program will not print anything. Other than an Exception when the socket times out of course.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly, never would have thought about that.

Comment: Modifying what the server sends is usually the wrong way to go. You can also read from a socket without waiting for a newline character.